# MemSQL performance issues

Tags: performance, memory, resources, cpu, singlestore

I have a single node MemSQL install with one master aggregator and two leaves (all on a single box). The machine has 2 cores, 16Gb RAM, and MemSQL columnstore data is ~7Gb (coming from 21Gb CSV). When running queries on the data, memory usage caps at ~2150Mb (11Gb sitting free). I've configured both leaves to have maximum_memory = 7000 in the memsql.cnf files for both nodes (memsql-optimize does similar). During query execution, the master aggregator sits at 100% CPU, with the leaves 0-8% CPU.

This does not seems like an efficient use of system resources, but I'm not sure what I can do to configure the system or MemSQL to make more efficient use of CPU or memory. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My database was coming from some other place than the current memsql install (perhaps an older cluster configuration) despite there only being a single memsql cluster on the machine. Looking at the Databases section in the Web UI was displaying no databases/tables, but my queries were succeeded with the expected answers.

drop database/reload from CSV managed to remedy the situation. All core threads are now used during query.

Answer (score 0):

If during query execution your machine is at 100% cpu (on all cores), it doesn't really matter which MemSQL node it is, your workload throughput is still bottlenecked on cpu. However for most queries you wouldn't expect most of the cpu use to be on the aggregator, so you may want to take a look at EXPLAIN or PROFILE of your queries.

Columnstore data is cached in memory as part of the OS file cache - it isn't counted as memory reserved by MemSQL, which is why your memory usage is less than the size of the columnstore data.

Comment: Thanks, file cache makes sense. During query execution, only one thread on one core is constant at 100% (mostly the aggregator), the other 3 (2 threads on other core) have very little CPU usage. I'll take a look at explain and see what I can find.